# linux + mount from local dir

Tags: linux, mount, find

in my Linux machine I run the following command under 
from **/usr/cti/APPS** directory

```
   cd /usr/cti/APPS
   mount -t nfs $server:$target_dir /mnt
```

I want to show something very interesting

I can run the following find command from any directory in my linux machine as ( /var/tmp , /usr/cti , /etc/APP/conf ) and get results

```
    /bin/find /mnt/DIR  -name *.txt*
```

but when I run the find command from  **/usr/cti/APPS** directory , then find command not print any  results ,

Please advice why I can’t get results from the directory that was performed the mount?
And how to fix that?

example

```
    cd /usr/cti/APPS

    /bin/find /mnt/DIR  -name *.txt* 

    NOT GET ANY OUTPUT


    cd ..

    /bin/find /mnt/DIR  -name *.txt* 

    GET RESULTS
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a cross post with http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144289/linux-mount-to-target-directory-from-local-dir-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very easy, it is because you have files matching the `*.txt*` pattern inside `/usr/cti/APPS` and the shell expands your expression. Try to use `'*.txt*'` instead of `*.txt*` in the find expression.

Comment: not so easy for me